# msdeploy folder outside documentroot of target site

Tags: asp.net, iis, msdeploy

So currently i've got my CI-setup working with msdeploy where my solution is deployed to a IIS website on a Azure VM. With this setup i've got a wpp.targets file to add some extra files (like assets) that are copied to some other folder. Also got a parameters.xml to change some settings for the environment i'm deploying to.

So far so good.

Now I need to sync a folder that need to be outside of the documentroot of the IIS app. It's just a folder with a bunch of plain text files, but that are used by the application and may not be accessed by our visitors (although it's just for a test/staging-environment, on production we'll do this action manually).

Anyone knows if msdeploy is able to do this?

I'm considering to maybe create a new IIS (virtual) application and restrict access to visitor to just deploy to that app. But I don't think this is a very clean way and a waste of the resources it's using...

It would be very helpful if anyone knows a better way. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

MSDeploy can be used to sync any directories between the source and destination, even those not part of an IIS application.

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:iisApp=c:\localSourceDirectory -dest:iisApp=c:\inetpub\destinationDirectory,computerName=Foobar,...
```

The iisApp provider supports actual physical directories in addition to IIS virtual directories.